# Куда делись скобки после функций типа this в js?

Tags: javascript, функции, this

недавно, вызвав функцию **length**, как обычно, со скобками, словил ошибку. Посидев некоторое время пришел к выводу, что скобки надо убрать - все заработало. Но сегодня столкнулся с следующей проблемой: я не могу вызвать свою функцию с **this**. Пример:

```
const Cube = {
    height : 100,
    width : 100,
    dipth : 100,
    position : { x : 10, y : 10, z : 10 },
};

const Move = this.Move = (sX, sY, sZ) => {
    this.position.x += sX;
    this.position.y += sY;
    this.position.z += sZ;
};

Cube.Move(10, 0, 0);
```

итогом выдает ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: Cube.Move is not a function`
Но если я пишу без скобок `Cube.Move;`, ошибок ,соответственно, нет.

Answer (score 2):

> если я пишу без скобок `Cube.Move;`, ошибок ,соответственно, нет.

Ну, если цель - только чтобы не было ошибок, то все в порядке.

---

Вы не показали код с `length`, но, если речь о строке/коллекции/массиве, то это свойство, а не метод. Поэтому никакие скобки не нужны.

---

```js
const Cube = {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  depth: 100,
  position: { x: 10, y: 10, z: 10 }
};

Cube.Move = function(sX, sY, sZ) {
  this.position.x += sX;
  this.position.y += sY;
  this.position.z += sZ;
};

Cube.Move(10, 0, 0);
console.log(Cube.position);
```

или сразу при объявлении объекта:

```js
const Cube = {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  depth: 100,
  position: { x: 10, y: 10, z: 10 },
  Move: function(sX, sY, sZ) {
    this.position.x += sX;
    this.position.y += sY;
    this.position.z += sZ;
  }
};

Cube.Move(10, 0, 0);
console.log(Cube.position);
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в вопросе, кажется, две путаницы.

1. Со скобками можно вызвать только то, что является функцией. Чаще всего свойство `length` не является функцией, поэтому скобки при нем не нужны.
2. `this` равняется родительскому объекту только внутри его функций вызванных как методы. Вне методов объекта, в глобальной области видимости `this` равняется чаще всего или глобальному объекту (`window`), или `undefined`, в зависимости от режима strict. В вашем случае скорее всего функция присваивалась `window`, поэтому она не находилась в `Cube`.

Вдобавок стрелочные функции не стоит использовть как методы, потому что `this` в них не будет равно родительскому объекту.

Поэтому в вашем случае скорее всего нужно так:

```js
const Cube = {
    height : 100,
    width : 100,
    dipth : 100,
    position : { x : 10, y : 10, z : 10 },
};

Cube.Move = function(sX, sY, sZ) {
    this.position.x += sX;
    this.position.y += sY;
    this.position.z += sZ;
};

Cube.Move(10, 0, 0);

console.log(Cube);
```